# How to stream a video with youtube-dl in Python 3

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I would like to stream the audio of a youtube video in python, `youtube-dl` allows me to download a video (audio in my case), but that process can take some time. My objective is to be able to stream the audio 'dynamically', like I would by going on a youtube video. I would like to start playing the audio and still download the rest of it at the same time.

I know that the `youtube-dl` command line program allows to stream videos to media players, like VLC for example:
`youtube-dl -o - -- "[videoID]" | vlc -`. I could create a subprocess and execute that command, but I would prefer to use a cleaner way, if possible.

I would expect to have some sort of data that I can transmit to an audio device later on. I don't need to store the audio in a file, but it's not a big deal if there is a temporary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible. Youtube-DL does not expose an API that makes this straightforward. [This](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/fffc618c519d10a7335eb5b06ab13d56ecea8561/youtube_dl/utils.py#L2030-L2059) is where Youtube-DL opens the file (or stdout) for writing. It's not exactly written to allow for easy switching of the output stream.

It's probably easier to just subprocess it and pipe its output if you really want this functionality.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible because `mpv` uses `youtube-dl` in exactly this manner, and even allows seeking, which is not possible with just a pipe.